# Markdown Here:Tables do not display correctly upon toggling to markdown

Tags: markdown

Try as I might, I am unable to get the tables to render correctly in the GMail email editing window. I have used the tables in the [cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Here-Cheatsheet#wiki-tables), but these have failed to work; I have tried writing separate tables based on the same format, but these have also failed to render as expected. As I have too little reputation, I am unable to post an image showing the issue, but the table I have written and which is displaying incorrectly is

`Markdown | Less | Pretty`

`--- | --- | ---`

`*still | renders | **nicely*`

`1 | 2 |3`

Can anyone see why this is happening? Should I create a new issue on github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: You should create an issue on Github or post to the [Markdown Here Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/markdown-here). However...

One problem in your example is that your inline MD is a bit off -- you don't have matching asterisks around "still" and "nicely". For example, this works fine for me:

```
Markdown | Less | Pretty
--- | --- | ---
*still* | renders | **nicely**
1 | 2 |3
```

Or... it worked fine for me *after* I deleted some extra newlines that may have been introduced in my copy-pasting of your example. Maybe. If you copy my example above and then "paste as plain text" into your email it should work.

Does that fix your problem? If not, I encourage you to upload a screenshot someplace that we can see here. (Or create a Github issue or GGroup post. But now that we're rolling on StackOverflow...)

Also: What browser and OS?

Comment: That did fix my issue! I'm not sure I understand what went wrong, though I suppose it must have been the newlines... Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem basically because the ENTER. Please use SHIFT + ENTER instead of ENTER when you want to create table using Markdown Here in GMail.

Hope this answer can solve your issue with Markdown Here table.